# Page template name for standard posts in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

what is the default template name for posts in wordpress? - my theme is currently using index.php to display posts. - i have created an 'archive.php but it's not using it, I wondered if I had missed something.

Answer (score 0):

- Single posts: *single.php*
- All posts (Blog): *index.php*

[image: Template Hierarchy]

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy for further documentation.

Comment: I know its already using index.php which is kind of the last resort template but if I customise the template of this, its going to affect any page that uses that template surely

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. You can use conditional tags inside index.php e.g. _is_single()_ or _is_page()_ to specify... [See Documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)

Comment: i am just wondering what template it uses - the page of posts - according to this it should be archive.php - but its just defaulting to index.php

Comment: _archive.php_ is for archive pages (like tags, categories, authors etc.). Try _home.php_ or _front-page.php_ (if they don't exist, create them). Which one depends on your WP configuration.